# Steps to use .gitignore and .git/info/exclude

Tags: git, git-bash

I'm having trouble understanding how to use and write to a .gitignore, .git/config file and .git/info/exclude file.

I've read through [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1753070/how-do-i-configure-git-to-ignore-some-files-locally/1753078#1753078) and [this documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) but its just not clicking for me.

my understanding is that:
- .gitignore is to be used when you are okay with the file being pushed to git hub.
- use .git/info/exclude to keep files or folders from being pushed to git hub.  So this is where you would hid secrets like API keys or put large folders of photos that do not need to be in git hub but just on my machine for deep learning training.
Is this not accurate?

How can I write to the .gitignore or .git/info/exclude files using command line or git bash?  I've attempted many times by experimenting with syntax but am at a loss now.  And I also cannot figure out how to open them through jupyter interface.

Comment: *.gitignore* is exclusion from Git realm, meaning this one for not pushing or doing anything else with the local file(s). *.git/info/exclude* works in case if you have file tracked by Git, but then you would like not to update it anymore, because you, for example, adding secret key into it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When would you use .git/info/exclude instead of .gitignore to exclude files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22906851/when-would-you-use-git-info-exclude-instead-of-gitignore-to-exclude-files)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Files and folders included in your `.gitignore` file are NOT tracked in git, and thus are not pushed to GitHub.

If I wanted git to IGNORE a file, my `.gitignore` would look like so:

```
file_to_ignore.txt
```

You can ignore folders too:

```
folder_to_ignore/
```

If I wanted git to ignore everything EXCEPT for a file, my `.gitignore` would look like so:

```
*
!file_to_include.txt
```

`*` is a wildcard, which means *everything*. `!` means do *not* ignore this file/folder.

Comment: It doesn't explain the difference to *.git/info/exclude*.

Comment: @wcarhart https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23097368/git-ignore-vs-exclude-vs-assume-unchanged

Answer (score 2):

> my understanding is that:
>
> - .gitignore is to be used when you are okay with the file being pushed to git hub.
> - use .git/info/exclude to keep files or folders from being pushed to git hub. [snip]
>
> Is this not accurate?

This is not accurate.  Assuming you understand just what *untracked file* means: what both `.gitignore` and `.git/info/exclude` do for you is to prevent *accidentally* tracking a file, and to shut Git up from complaining about the untracked files.  That's pretty much it.  Once a file is *tracked*, the `.gitignore` and `.git/info/exclude` files no longer affect it.

Files can become tracked and untracked at various times, though.  There's a lot to know here.

#### Untracked files

The phrase *untracked file* has a very specific meaning in Git.  I would point to the [gitglossary](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary) here, but unfortunately *untracked file* is not defined there (!).  So, I will use my own definition:

- **untracked file**
  An untracked file is any file that *is* in the working tree right now, but *is not* in the index right now.

We'll come back to why I say *right now* twice, in a bit.  First, though, this uses two more terms, *index* and *working tree*, that this time *are* defined in the [gitglossary](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary):

> - **index**
>   A collection of files with stat information, whose contents are stored as objects. The index is a stored version of your [working tree](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary#def_working_tree). ...
> - **working tree**
>   The tree of actual checked out files. The working tree normally contains the contents of the [HEAD](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary#def_HEAD) commit’s tree, plus any local changes that you have made but not yet committed.

To get a good picture of all of this in your head, start with this: A Git repository is mainly composed of two databases.  One holds all your commits and other Git *objects* (essentially, the rest of the stuff you need for a commit: file names and file contents).  The other database, generally a lot smaller, holds your branch and tag name and other such names.  The smaller database maps names to hash IDs.

You will have seen hash IDs in `git log` output:

```
commit 745f6812895b31c02b29bdfe4ae8e5498f776c26
Author: Junio C Hamano ...
```

(This particular commit is in the Git repository for Git, which you can clone from http://github.com/git/git/ if you like.  [Here is that commit](https://github.com/git/git/commit/745f6812895b31c02b29bdfe4ae8e5498f776c26); if you clone the repository, you will have this commit.)

Every Git object has its own hash ID.  Each commit has a hash ID that is unique to that one particular commit.  That hash ID can never be used for any other commit.  Every other commit gets its own, *different* hash ID.  A branch name, like `master`, holds one (1) hash ID, and to add commits to a branch, Git stuffs a *new* hash ID into the name `master`, so branch names change which hash ID they mean, over time.

Meanwhile, the hash ID for each commit is totally static and permanent.  Once you have commit `745f6812895b31c02b29bdfe4ae8e5498f776c26`, commit `745f6812895b31c02b29bdfe4ae8e5498f776c26` is always *that* commit.  You either have it in your database of all-Git-objects, and then it's *that* commit, or you don't have it at all.  Nothing about this commit can *ever* be changed.  You either have it, and then it's exactly the same as the `745f6812895b31c02b29bdfe4ae8e5498f776c26` that I linked to above, or you don't have it.

Now, commits *contain* files—as a full snapshot—so if you have that particular commit, you have all of those files.  But the files inside *any* commit are in a special, read-only / frozen, Git-only, format.  I like to call them "freeze-dried".  These freeze-dried files can be reconstituted any time you like, but the defrosted and rehydrated files are just *copies*.  The originals are still inside the original commit.<sup>1</sup>

This means commits are great for archival—they keep copies of every version of every file, forever—but they're utterly useless for actually getting any new work done.  You *must* reconstitute the files in order to use them, and to do that, Git puts the reconstituted files into your *working tree*, or work-tree, or any name along these lines.

---

<sup>1</sup>Technically, they're in additional Git objects, to which the commit merely points.  Git is gradually acquiring a system by which they can be loaded on-demand rather than requiring that the commit come along with all of its dependencies, so someday you'll be able to have the commit without having the files too.  But for now they might as well be directly in the commit, except for the fact that commits can *share* the freeze-dried copies of files, if they haven't changed from one commit to another.

---

#### The index

The working tree, or work-tree, defined above is pretty straightforward:  Git's permanently-saved versions of files are in a special, read-only, Git-only format, so Git has to expand them out to ordinary, useful files, and put those into an area where you can see them and work with them.  That's actually something pretty much every version control system does.  Most just stop here—if there's anything more, the VCS keeps it hidden away.  Git is not like the other version control systems.  Git adds this thing it calls the *index*, and then promptly keeps shoving it in your face.

The index is also called the *staging area*, or sometimes—rarely these days—the *cache*.  These are all just three names for the same thing.  As the [gitglossary](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary) says, it's a collection of files.  In fact, initially, it's the files *from the commit you checked out:*

```
git checkout master
```

The name `master` is a branch name, so Git looks up the commit hash ID in its first database (of names to hash IDs).  The checkout puts you on branch `master` and extracts that commit—whatever its hash ID is—so that you have all of its files in your work-tree.  This extraction process obviously has to do:

- read from commit
- decompress / un-freeze / write to work-tree

If Git did just this—as other systems do—Git could use your work-tree, whatever changes you make to it, as your proposed *next* commit.  When you run `git commit`, Git would have to look through your work-tree, re-compress everything, and see if it's changed from the previous commit or not.  But instead, Git does this:

- read from commit
- write (frozen format, really hash ID) to index / staging-area
- decompress / un-freeze / write to work-tree

Now when you run `git commit` Git can *ignore* your work-tree and just re-freeze straight from the index.  If you made any changes in your work-tree, you *must* run:

```
git add whatever-file
```

to tell Git: *take whatever-file from the work-tree and compress it down to the freeze-dried form and put that into the index, ready to be committed*.

**In other words, instead of your work-tree being your proposed next commit, it's actually your *index* that is your proposed next commit.**  You can change anything you want in your work-tree without affecting your next commit, because it's what is in your index / staging-area that matters.

#### Both the index and your work-tree are per-repository temporary areas

What really matters, in Git, is the commits.  The big database, of all commits (and their files), is what Gits exchange between each other.  The smaller database, of names like branch and tag names—Gits *use* that to send each other commits, and Gits will send each other their names (which you can override if you like) so that the other Git can use that name, if it likes, to remember the commits.  But it's the commits that matter.

Your work-tree is *yours*, to do with as you will.  Git doesn't really use it, with a few exceptions:

- `git checkout` copies from commits, to the index and then your work-tree.  (It has other modes that do more things.  In some ways, it has too many modes, which is why in Git 2.23 there are *two* commands that, put together, can do what `git checkout` can do all in one command.)
- `git reset` copies from commits to the index (and sometimes to the work-tree too).  (Like `git checkout`, it has a lot of things it can do—perhaps too many.)
- `git add` copies from your work-tree to the index.
- `git status` *looks at* your work-tree.  It looks first at the current commit, then at the index, and then at your work-tree.

It's at these last two commands—`git add` and `git status`—that `.gitignore` and friends start to become useful.  But let's mention one more command:

- `git rm` removes files from both the index *and* your work-tree.  It has a mode where it only removes from the index, leaving the work-tree file alone.

When you run `git commit`, Git packages up the index contents into a new snapshot—a new commit—which then becomes the *current* commit, so now the commit and the index match again.  The work-tree is not changed during this process: if it used to match the index, it still does; if it didn't match the index, it still doesn't.

Hence, the index is a temporary area where you build the *next* commit, by staging files into it as desired.  All the files you *didn't* stage explicitly, but were already in the index because of the *previous* commit, are *still there*.  They go into the new snapshot.

#### How tracked / untracked works with `git add` and `git status`

What `git status` does—well, a big part of what it does, and all that we're concerned with right here—is to run *two* `git diff`s with, in effect, the `--name-status` option, and then display the results in a more useful form:

- The first diff compares the current commit to the index.  Whatever is *the same*, Git says nothing.  For each file that is *different*, Git tells you `staged for commit`.  So *updated* files in the index, which now differ from their `HEAD` version, are called *staged*.  Git is silent about other files.
- The second diff compares the index—the ready-to-be-committed, staged files—to the work-tree.  Whatever is *the same*, Git says nothing.  For each file that is *different*, Git tells you `not staged for commit`.  So updated files in the work-tree, which now differ from their ready-to-commit staged copies, are called *not staged*.

But you can have files in your work-tree that *aren't* in your index *right now*.  How did they get there?  Well, Git filled in your index—your staging area—when you ran `git checkout`.  If a file named `foo.config` wasn't there in the commit, it isn't there in the index.  If it wasn't written to the index, it wasn't written to your work-tree either.  But maybe *something you ran* created it in your work-tree.  Maybe you even worked with it.  So now it's there, in your work-tree, but not in your index.

What `git status` will do is *complain* about this file.  It will say: *untracked file*.  If you want `git status` to shut up about this file, you can list it in a `.gitignore` or a `.git/info/exclude`, and `git status` *won't* complain.

This has no effect on whether `foo.config` is in the index.  We already said that it's *not* in the index, so it's still not in the index when `git status` doesn't complain.  But that still leaves `git add`.  If you run:

```
git add foo.config
```

you're telling Git: *freeze-dry the work-tree copy and put that in the index.*  If you do that without any `.gitignore` or similar, Git will obey, and `foo.config` will now be *in* your index.

If it's not in the current commit, `git status` will tell you that it's newly added and ready to be committed (staged for commit), too.  It's there, in the index, so it *will* be in the next commit.

If you don't *want* it to be in the next commit, you have to *remove it from the index:*

```
git rm foo.config
```

and now it's gone from the index *and* from your work-tree.  If you didn't want it gone from your work-tree, use:

```
git rm --cached foo.config
```

and now it's gone from the index, but still in your work-tree, and now `git status` will complain about it as *untracked*.  You might add it to a `.gitignore` or `exclude` file, so as to stop the complaining.

Adding it to the exclude file *while it's untracked* (i.e., not in the index, but in the work-tree) has one other beneficial side effect.  Besides the kind of `git add` above, you can do:

```
git add .
```

or:

```
git add *
```

to add a whole bunch of files en-masse.  If `foo.config` is currently untracked (i.e., not in the index but in the work-tree), and `git add` comes across an attempt to add it, `git add` *won't* add it by default.  So it will remain untracked.

Note, however, that if you force the file into the index in any way—such as, for instance, by doing `git checkout` of a commit that *does* have `foo.config` in it—the file is now *tracked*, because it's *in the index*.  A file that is in the index—however it got that way—is tracked.  A file that isn't in the index—however it got that way—is untracked.

#### Putting it all together

> ... hide secrets like API keys or put large folders of photos that do not need to be in git hub ...

When you `git push` to GitHub, you send it *commits*.  Whatever snapshots are in those commits, go to GitHub.  If you want to be sure that `secret.key` and `big.file` don't go, you need to make sure they don't go into the index and hence do not go into any new commits.

To keep them from going into the index, they should *start out* that way—not in the index and not in any *existing* commits, that would get them *into* the index on a `git checkout`.  If they're already in some such commits, you can either avoid those commits, or—but this is kind of hard—work hard and actually get rid of those commits—but if you don't, you're in good shape to start with.

To keep from *accidentally* putting the files into the index and hence into new commits, simply list the two file names in *either or both* of a `.gitignore` or a `.git/info/exclude`.  If you put the names into a `.gitignore`, you can then `git add .gitignore` and make a new commit.  From now on, that `.gitignore` is in that commit, and gets copied out of that commit into the index for every additional new commit you make *from* that commit.  So the two names `secret.key` and `big.file` won't *accidentally* get into the index, and hence won't accidentally get into new commits.

You don't *have* to do either of these.  All you *have* to do is make sure that no *new* commits make snapshots of those files.  New commits make snapshots from the index, so you just have to make sure you don't accidentally copy `secret.key` and/or `big.file` into the index.

If for some reason you really want those in some commit(s), you *can* do that, but now you have to make sure that you never send *those* commits—the ones that have snapshots of `secret.key` and `big.file`—never go to GitHub.  That's a fair bit harder.  You're better off putting these files in a separate repository, if you want to version-control them at all.

The dot-files, `.gitignore` and `.git/info/exclude`, are really about:

- keeping files that are currently untracked, untracked in the future too
- without having to do that carefully / by hand
- without `git status` whining about them

The `.gitignore` file itself can be put in the index, so that there are copies in each commit snapshot.  Since new clones use the original commits, new clones have those.  The `.git/info/exclude` file cannot be put in the index, so there are no copies of that in any snapshot, and new clones will not have it.

Answer (score 1):

The main difference between `.gitignore` and `info/exclude` is that the first is versioned and can be checked in and checked out together with other files. There for it is persistent across multiple repositories.

`info/exclude` is not version controlled and affects only a single repository. You would need to physically copy it to another repository to have an effect there.

Both files are used to prevent git from tracking yet *untracked* files. They do not affect files which are already committed.

The `core.excludeFile` is yet another mechanism to possibly specify a system-wide ignore file.

Documentation specifies an order in which git considers the files: .gitingore, info/exlude, then core.excludeFile.

The example when you need the file could be build which generates .o files in the same worktree as the source files. They `*.o` pattern could be put in any of those files. It will make mos of the git commands to forget about existence of those files. They will not be listed in 'git status' or will not be added by 'git add'.

As such, the files can only be used to prevent from a adding *untracked* files into your local git repository. But as soon as you managed to commit the untracked files, nothing will prevent them from being pushed.